# Convert video file to binary file - and then convert binary file to video file

Tags: c#, vb.net

I basically need to do 4 steps:

- Step 1 : convert video file to binary file
- Step 2 : change binary structure (encryption)
- Step 3 : refix binary structure (decryption)
- Step 4 : convert binary file to video file

But the hardest thing I face is **step 4**.

What is the simplest method I can use to convert a binary file to video file?

Comment: Did you mean Video File ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Video files are already binary files, in that they're not text files. Why do you think you need to convert them before encrypting?

Comment: Are you trying to conver a Video file into a byte[] array or something ?

Comment: it sounds like #2 and #3 are the main intention, in which case, you certainly do not need to convert the *file* to binary anything. first you need to decide on which encryption method you want to use - NET has several - because that will determine what to do next.

Comment: i will re explain what i mean i need to make physical encrypted file by changing some byte structure and then re fix this file by fix his byte structure that's what i mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you are trying to convert a file to byte array then this it's very easy

```
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(pathToFile)
```

Comment: Given how large video files can be, loading the entire thing into memory is probably a bad idea though. The encryption or decryption should be performed in a streaming manner if possible.