# Convert video file or data to binary code in C#

Tags: c#, binary

I need to convert a video file or data to binary code. I know video file is binary, but when I change the video file to "video.bin", I see a lot of alphabet and I need to convert binary code and vice versa (to video file or data).
I looked up this post:

[Convert video file to binary file - and then convert binary file to video file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19874160/convert-video-file-to-binary-file-and-then-convert-binary-file-to-video-file)

but didn't solve my problem.

Comment: That is "binary code".  You're just interpreting it as ASCII or Unicode characters.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: i need to compress binary code

Comment: i have video file how to compress it with c# and convert it to the string

Comment: All files are binary.  You don't have any actual problem.  And you should not convert binary data to a string.  You need to learn to work with byte arrays or `Stream`.

Comment: my question is could decrease size of video with c#

Comment: Then you need to learn about byte arrays and compression, and perhaps video codecs.  Good luck.

Comment: @SLaks hi i find the way but i couldn't convert binary to mp4 this is my code

Comment: byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(f);
            textBox2.Text = string.Join(" ", bytes.Select(b => Convert.ToString(b, 2).ToUpper()));